# How can I use opencv-python to convert RGB888 to RGB565 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rgb, opencv, python

I would like to read camera image by **opencv-python** and send image raw data (byte array) in RGB565 format to device.
Here are some testing codes:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # open camera
flag, image = cam.read() # read image from camera
show = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480)) # resize to 640x480
show = cv2.cvtColor(show, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to RGB888
```

After codes run, it returned **"show"** ndarray (numpy) by cvtColor at last line, the **"show"** ndarray info is:

```
>>> show.shape
(480, 640, 3)
>>> show.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> show.size
921600
```

I don't see any convert code about cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB**565**, is there any other function to support RGB888 to RGB565?

Or someone knows how to convert **ndarray** RGB888 to RGB565?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is right but don't have anything RGB565 to test it on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Get some deterministic randomness and synthesize small image
np.random.seed(42)
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(1,4,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# In [67]: im
# Out[67]:
# array([[[102, 220, 225],
#        [ 95, 179,  61],
#        [234, 203,  92],
#        [  3,  98, 243]]], dtype=uint8)

# Make components of RGB565
R5 = (im[...,0]>>3).astype(np.uint16) << 11
G6 = (im[...,1]>>2).astype(np.uint16) << 5
B5 = (im[...,2]>>3).astype(np.uint16)

# Assemble components into RGB565 uint16 image
RGB565 = R5 | G6 | B5

# Produces this:
# array([[26364, 23943, 61003,   798]], dtype=uint16)
```

---

Or, you can remove your `cv2.cvtColor(show, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` and swap the indices to:

```
R5 = (im[...,2]>>3).astype(np.uint16) << 11
G6 = (im[...,1]>>2).astype(np.uint16) << 5
B5 = (im[...,0]>>3).astype(np.uint16)
```

Comment: By the way Mark, may I ask if my code below is correct to transfer RGB565 to byte array or not?

raw = RGB565.tobytes()

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm just new to python, may ask some basic questions frequently. ^^

Comment: It's ok... we're all here to learn. And questions are free, same as answers! :-)

Comment: Hi Mark, I have the similar question about RGB565 to RGB888 with testing code, but I got stuck...XD, please help me if you got time. ^^
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816430/how-can-i-use-python-to-convert-rgb565-byte-array-to-rgb888-byte-array.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the usual `cvtColor()` function from OpenCV?  I see enums such as `COLOR_BGR2BGR565`, `COLOR_BGR5652BGR`, `COLOR_BGR5652RGB`, and `COLOR_RGBA2BGR565` among others.  Wouldn't it be better to use OpenCV to do the conversion vs writing your own?

Comment: Hi Stephane, it's 2 years ago, I almost forget why I ask this question. I re-check the enums and found there is no enum to convert RGB888 to RGB565, that's why I ask this question. The purpose I need it is because I need RGB565 format data to be sent to my device for inference. If I use COLOR_BGR2BGR565, I still need a function to convert BGR565 to RGB565, so if I can get the answer directly from RGB888 to RGB565, then it's more convinient :)