# How can I use Python to convert RGB565 byte array to RGB888 byte array?

Tags: python, numpy, rgb

According to my question for [RGB888 to RGB565](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519934/how-can-i-use-opencv-python-to-convert-rgb888-to-rgb565-in-python), I would like to do RGB565 to RGB888, here is my testing code, however I got stuck on convert to RGB888 byte array.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(1,4,2), dtype=np.uint8)

# >>> im.nbytes
# 8
# >>> im
# array([[[102, 220],
#        [225,  95],
#        [179,  61],
#        [234, 203]]], dtype=uint8)

# Make components of RGB888
R8 = (im[...,0] & 0xF8).astype(np.uint32) << 8
G8 = (im[...,0] & 0x07).astype(np.uint32) << 5 | (im[...,1] & 0xE0).astype(np.uint32)
B8 = (im[...,1] & 0x1F).astype(np.uint32)
RGB888 = R8 | G8 | B8

# >>> RGB888.nbytes
# 16 <= here I think it should be 12 (4x3 bytes)

# >>> RGB888.reshape(1, 4, 3)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (1,4,3)
```

When I use astype(np.uint16), some values become 0 because it need larger data type to store, that's why I use unit32 on above code.

I know unit32 will make above code's RGB888 size to be 16, so I would like to ask if any other correct way to transfer RGB565 to RGB888?

Comment: You should start from a 2-dimensional `np.uint16` array where each element corresponds to a single packed pixel.

Comment: As @AKX says, RGB565 is naturally a `uint16` type, so it would make more sense to start with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should get you from RGB565 `uint16` to three uint8 channel arrays, which you can then `dstack` into a single 3-dimensional RGB image:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
im = np.random.randint(0,65536,(4,4), dtype=np.uint16)

MASK5 = 0b011111
MASK6 = 0b111111

# TODO: BGR or RGB? Who knows!
b = (im & MASK5) << 3
g = ((im >> 5) & MASK6) << 2
r = ((im >> (5 + 6)) & MASK5) << 3

# Compose into one 3-dimensional matrix of 8-bit integers
rgb = np.dstack((r,g,b)).astype(np.uint8)
```

EDIT: to convert an W x H x 2 array of uint8s into a W x H array of uint16s,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(4,4,2), dtype=np.uint8)

b1 = im[:,:,0].astype(np.uint16)
b2 = im[:,:,1].astype(np.uint16)
im = (b1 << 8 | b2)
```

You may need to swap b1 and b2 around depending on the endianness of your source array.

Comment: You can stack with `RGB = np.dstack((r,g,b))` :-)

Comment: Cheers Mark :) Adding that in. (Funny that `stack`'s documentation doesn't link to `dstack`...)

Comment: OP may also need `.astype(np.uint8)` tacked on the end, since we started with `np.uint16`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yup, fair point (though I'm sure OP'd notice sooner rather than later! :-D )

Comment: I think the generic function is `np.stack()`. You can get vertical stacking with `np.vstack()` or using `np.stack(axis=0)`. Then you get horizontal stacking with `np.hstack()` or `np.stack(axis=1)`. And depth stacking with `np.dstack()` or `np.stack(axis=2)`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Seeing as `split` already had see-alsos for the variants, I figured why not make a PR to fix the docs :) https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/16249

Comment: Hi AKX and Mark, thanks for your quick responses and I will try it later. ^^

Comment: Hi AKX, if my source is 4x4x2 byte array (because I got it from somewhere), how can I convert it to the 4x4 uint16 array like your code "im" above?